Flutter when i add item to List whole List rebuilds ( is there any solution withGetx,Riverpod,Bloc,Provider or any other state management package?)
 return Obx(   
     ()=> ListView.builder(
        addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
        cacheExtent: 10,/*  */
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: belirleyengun.length /*  5*/,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
          print('a');
       ...

It prints an equal to the length of the list. is there any possible way to add new item without rebuilding the whole list with provider riverpod or bloc or getx (i prefer getx solution so much)
my code is here i have tried with obx and getxcontroller the results were the same

As far as I know, there is no way, because when the value of Rx changes, it will rebuild the entire Obx

is there any way with other state management packgaes like bloc riverpod provider and can you upvote this for to see other peoples it is so important for me
